# Haskell command system parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I've written this simple parser that take from the command line [ps auxww | ./myparser] and parses the output of the ps command in order to insert it into the process data structure I created.
I succeed to parse one line of the result String, but now I'm stuck trying to parse the whole string and return a [Process] and not a single Process. The problem is how to implement parsePS. It has to call many times myParser in order to parse every single line and return a list of Process and print it into the terminal.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's failing for you, but I am guessing the spacing is killing you.  If so, I have two ideas that might help.

Modify `myParser` to consume spaces at the end and the `many` combinator should work.

```
myParser = do
  ...
  spaces
  command <- pCommand
  spaces -- CONSUME END OF LINE
  return Entry{ ... }
```

Then `many myParser` should work.

Alternately, you could split the input into lines separately first and call parse on each.

```
  argLines <- fmap lines getContents
```

(I take it you mean to burn the first line via `getLine` before the `hGetContents`?)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for a way to parse each line in sequence and return a list of parsed results. How about [mapM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) from the Prelude?

If `myParser :: String -> Parser Process`, then `mapM myParser :: [String] -> Parser [Process]`, which seems to be what you're looking for (using generic names for `Parsec`'s Parser types). So if you have a list of lines (call it `lns`) that you want to parse in sequence, you can use `parse (mapM myParser) lns` to get what you want.